# Django Rest Framework Excel File Upload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

Note: Please read the whole question before marking it as duplicate.

Django has changed **ALOT** Since a couple of years.

I have already tried all the solutions and read Django Rest Framework Documentation on:

- FileUploadPasrer
  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser
- MultiPartParser
  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser.

None of the ways work. I also tried uploading using simple Django but that didnt seem to work Either.

**The Error I am getting is that request.FILES['file'] is always an empty {}.**

Write now my code looks like this

```
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj1 = request.data['file']
        data = json.loads(request.POST['form'])
        print(file_obj1)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Like i said I always tried Using ***FileUploadParser***. Same code just replaced MultiPartParser with FileUploadParser. I am using Postman to send an excel file and then reading it. Anyone who has recently upload an excel file in Django Rest Framework can guide me but make sure your code works becuase I have already spent a day and still can't find the solution so far.

Edit: Curl Request from Postman would be: `curl --location 'http://localhost:8000/amm-api/upload/upload_workbook/' \ --form '=@"/Users/razan/Projects/HTS/ags-carmax/Robbie_Lisa-Branch.xlsx"'`

This is how it looks in Postman [image]

Comment: did you use form data?

Comment: `I am using Postman to send an excel file and then reading it.` Can you export the postman request as cURL and include it in the question? There are many ways to send a file to a server, and the way you access the file depends on how the file is being sent.

Comment: I also added in the  Update but Its this:  ```curl --location 'http://localhost:8000/amm-api/upload/upload_workbook/' \
--form '=@"/Users/razan/Projects/HTS/ags-carmax/Robbie_Lisa-Branch.xlsx"'```

Comment: @KayesFahim Yes I have. Added the Postman screenshot in the main question for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 2 days over it I have finally found a way by hit and try. Please try it and let me know. As of today it works on Django 3.8.2

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
import pandas as pd
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class FileUploadView(APIView):
parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
    try:
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        file_content = file_obj.read()
        df = pd.read_excel(file_content, engine='openpyxl')
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'message': 'File uploaded.'})
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        return Response({'status': 'error', 'message': error_message})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views
from amm_core.views import FileUploadView

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
]
```

**settings.py** (Make sure to include the certain permissions.)

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    ],
 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
```

Then from Postman hit the API with and excel selected.
`http://localhost:8000/<app-name><optional-sub-appname>/upload/<filename>.xlsx`
[image: Postman image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get the original scenario (APIView with POST handler using MultiPartParser) to work, and I finally got it done.

I'm going to summarize everything I found as succinctly as possible, then explain:

- To handle properly a mixed HTML form which includes data AND files, you need to use 2 parsers at the same time: `MultiPartParser` and `FormParser`.
- `request.FILES['file']` will come empty if your form doesn't include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
- If you are using Postman (like you were, and like I was), and you are **NOT using FileUploadParser and PUT method**, you NEED to add a Key to the file being sent in the form-data, and this Key must be the same you are trying to read from the `request.FILES['file']` dictionary (**so the key in Postman should be 'file'**).

This will make it work.

Now, I'll go in some detail for those who still need it:

- In the initial solution posted by @nabiharaza he switches from MultiPartParser to FileUploadParser to make it work. This is fine if you don't intend to send additional form stuff with the file. But if you are sending mixed form data, you must use MultiPartParser and FormParser, like this:

```
class FileUploadAPI(APIView):

    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):

    # etc etc
```

- When you use MultiPartParser, you are going to get a dictionary (MultiValueDict) on `request.FILES`, which you can access by key. But [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) warns us that if we don't have the **enctype** set to **multipart/form-data** the dictionary will come empty. That's the main issue here.

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
> was POST, at least one file field was actually posted, and the 
> that posted the request has the attribute
> enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

(from the Django Docs link above).

In HTML, it would look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url catalog_create_ajax_upload %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="create-form">
```

But there is *one more thing* (see what I did here? :D) for those of us using Postman:

- On Postman, when you use the POST method, and select a file in the **form-data** section, it automatically creates a form with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute, so you don't need to add it manually by yourself. But you still need to set the **KEY** corresponding to the file (this is not mandatory for the PUT method handled by `FileUploadParser` because of how it works). If you check the original screenshot from @nabiharaza, you will notice that there isn't a key associated to the file **Robbie_Lisa-Branch.xlsx**.

So, even if everything else is correct, the `request.FILES` dictionary will come empty, and the `request.FILES['file']` access will throw an Exception.

If you add the `file` key to Postman, it will work like a charm :)

[image: form-data with proper file key]

Of course, if you have several files or you want to use `something_else` instead of `file` you can, but you need to match it in your dictionary access to `request.FILES['something_else']`.

I hope this is helpful for anyone trying to get this working and still struggling. I found bits and pieces of this info scattered all around the web (StackOverflow included) but not together on a single place.

Have fun!